# Bootstrap make rows in neighbouring columns the same height (in Laravel)

Tags: css, laravel, height, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a calendar app with a header row and header column, which shows six days in columns and has a fixed number of time periods per day.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md col-sm-12 mt-3 border border-secondary" style="background-color:lightgray">
        <div class="row text-center"><strong>Period</strong></div>
        @foreach ( config('enums.class_periods') as $key => $class_period)
            <div class="row border-top border-secondary text-center d-flex align-content-stretch flex-wrap"><strong>{{ $class_period }}</strong></div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @foreach ($week_array as $weekday)
    <div class="col-md col-sm-12 mt-3 border border-secondary {{$weekday==$today ? "border-primary" : "" }}" style="{{ $loop->even ? "background-color:lightgray":"" }}">
        <div class="row text-center"><strong>{{ $weekday }}</strong></div>
        @foreach ( config('enums.class_periods') as $key => $class_period)
            <div class="row border-top border-secondary text-center"><p>-</p></div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach        
</div>
```

[image: View of the table]

I need to make the rows in the header (first) column the same height as the rows in the day columns. This is because the data in the day columns' rows will be dynamic so that it can stretch a lot. I know I could change the layout to row by row instead of a column by column, but that will make the wrapping on smaller screens not the way I'd like it to be. I've played with several different suggestions that I found online but didn't find one that will work for me. Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you that viewed the question.

I've found a way to do this with jQuery by adapting the answer in this thread: [Bootstrap equal height rows inside equal height columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482167/bootstrap-equal-height-rows-inside-equal-height-columns)
I've adapted it this way:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md col-sm-12 mt-3 border border-secondary h-auto" style="background-color:lightgray">
        <div class="row text-center"><strong>Period</strong></div>
        @foreach ( config('enums.class_periods') as $key => $class_period)
            <div class="row border-top border-secondary text-center Row{{$loop -> iteration;}}"><strong>{{ $class_period }}</strong></div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @foreach ($week_array as $weekday)
    <div class="col-md col-sm-12 mt-3 border border-start-0 border-secondary" style="{{ $loop->even ? "background-color:lightgray;":"" }} {{$weekday==$today ? "background-color:lightblue" : "" }}">
        <div class="row text-center" style="background-color: lightgray"><strong>{{ $weekday }}</strong></div>
        @foreach ( config('enums.class_periods') as $key => $class_period)
            <div class="row border-top border-secondary text-center Row{{$loop -> iteration;}}"><p>-</p></div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach        
</div>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var periods = @json(config('enums.class_periods'));
        $.each(periods, function( index, value ) {
            var maxHeightRow = -1;
            $('.Row'+index).each(function() {
                maxHeightRow = maxHeightRow > $(this).height() ? maxHeightRow : $(this).height();
            });
            $('.Row'+index).each(function() {
                $(this).height(maxHeightRow);
            });
        });
    });  
</script>
```